# Why does my pandas dataframe have two names for each column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm primarily an R user, and indexes and headers in pandas confuse me sometimes.

I want just a basic dataframe, but when I use groupby and reset_index it creates this double header situation. This makes sub setting and creating plots really annoying. How do I get rid of organization_form and rev_giftsgrants_tot_curyr as headers?

```
grouped_form = rev.groupby('organization_form').agg({'rev_giftsgrants_tot_curyr': ['mean','std', 'min', 'max','sum']})
grouped_form = grouped_form.reset_index(col_fill = "Organization Form")
grouped_form
```

[image]

Getting the column names:

```
for col in grouped_form.columns: 
    print(col)
```

I get this:

[image]

I just want the characters after the comma to be the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `agg` by

```
grouped_form = rev.groupby('organization_form')['rev_giftsgrants_tot_curyr'].agg(['mean','std', 'min', 'max','sum']).reset_index()
```